# Git - My branch is not updating with the latest master

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-pull

I'm experiencing a really frustrating problem with my branch on bitbucket. I've seen several other similar problems on here but unfortunately, none of the answers really helped.

Whenever I start working on my branch I usually use `git fetch && git checkout 'branch name'`.

After that, I would add my relevant commits and push onto the master. Now I'm trying to retrieve the latest changes from the master, by doing a `git pull origin master`, however, I keep getting a message saying that it's already up-to-date, but this is not the case, as I'm not getting the latest changes on my branch.

Comment: I'm not following... you're pulling changes to master and expecting to see them on your branch?  I think the problem is that you're giving a general description of what you did and what happened, but to help we probably need to see the specific commands you issued, the specific output of those commands, and how that output differs from what you expect

Comment: @fabiog Rather than us answering your questions with a list of commands that you probably won't really understand, let me encourage you to take 30-60 minutes and go through a git tutorial. (An example one is here: learngitbranching.js.org).  Just a little bit of time spent understanding the fundamentals will make your experience of working with git MUCH more enjoyable and productive.

Answer (score 0):

In Git, commits are the coin of the realm (the things that get created, stored, pushed and pulled between your local Git and a remote Git, etc.), and branches are effectively distinct named worlds for working with commits.

So, if you say

```
git fetch && git checkout 'branch name'
```

then the world you are working in is `branch name`. You can edit your files, add, and commit, and those commits are appended to `branch name`.

Meanwhile, `master` is a *different* branch and is completely unaffected by what you have been doing. Neither pushing `master` nor pulling `master` will involve those commits in any way; those commits are on `branch name`, not `master`.